# Nmap - multiple hosts with the same MAC address

Tags: mac-address, hosts, nmap

I'm using nmap on my local network and saw that the output of `sudo nmap 192.168.1.0/24` has multiple hosts that have the same MAC address.

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.120
Host is up (0.13s latency).
MAC Address: B6:B0:24:0F:58:49 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.185
Host is up (0.018s latency).
MAC Address: B6:B0:24:0F:58:49 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.201
Host is up (0.060s latency).
MAC Address: B6:B0:24:0F:58:49 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.202
Host is up (0.060s latency).
MAC Address: B6:B0:24:0F:58:49 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.204
Host is up (0.063s latency).
MAC Address: B6:B0:24:0F:58:49 (Unknown)
```

In what situation would this happen? I've searched around but haven't found any resources on this.

After doing a tcp port scan of one of the hosts, I see the the following:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-22 18:20 CDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.185
Host is up (0.0083s latency).
Not shown: 65533 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
20002/tcp open  commtact-http
MAC Address: B6:B0:24:0F:58:49 (Unknown)
```

I've [read from this post](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/738581/question-about-tp-link-port-20002-and-commtact-http/) that it may be a wifi extender, but I wouldn't expect the ssh port to be open on that.

EDIT:

I think if this were a wifi extender, having `ssh`, `http`, and `commtact` open would make sense if the extender had some sort of remote access as well as a login page. As running `nmap -p 80 --script http-auth-finder 192.168.1.185` outputs:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
| http-auth-finder: 
| Spidering limited to: maxdepth=3; maxpagecount=20; withinhost=192.168.1.185
|   url                                                               method
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/locale/language.js                        HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/themes/default/css/perfect-scrollbar.css  HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/js/su/language.js                         HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/themes/default/css/total.css              HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/js/libs/respond.min.js                    HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/js/su/frame.js                            HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/js/su/widget.other.js                     HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/themes/default/css/total.ie8.css          HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/js/su/su.fun.js                           HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/js/su/widget.form.js                      HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/themes/default/css/base.css               HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/js/app/url.js                             HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|   http://192.168.1.172:80/themes/default/css/mobile.css             HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
|_  http://192.168.1.172:80/js/libs/jquery.min.js                     HTTP: Server returned no authentication headers.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a wifi extender. I have a TP-Link TL-WA850RE from Amazon with the same MAC-prefix. Weirdly this prefix is not documented in any MAC vendor database.

Thankfully this (2 days old) post got already indexed, since its the only thing I could find by googling :)

Nmap output:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.xxx
Host is up (0.0097s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     Cisco/3com IPSSHd 6.6.0 (protocol 2.0)
80/tcp open  http
```

NMAP output with MAC address:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.xxx
Host is up (0.070s latency).
MAC Address: B6:B0:24:07:**:** (Unknown)
```

Comment: Why are there multiple wifi extender hosts if there is only 1 wifi extender, though? E.g. one of the hosts with that same mac address has neo4j port 7474 open.

Comment: Either a issue with the extender OR the extender applies another MAC to traffic that goes through it. Doesn't really make any sense though, was just an idea.